# Hidden bootloader

Tags: bootloader

I need a bootloader that will work as described:

I want my computer to boot Windows, that is my main OS installed on a primary bootable partition. However, I'd like to have a 2-3 second span with blinking cursor, before Windows starts. If I press any key in that period it should launch Ubuntu from a small Truecrypt-encoded partition, upon providing a correct password.

In other words I'm looking for a hidden bootloader that would expose itself only when a key is pressed during a certain time. Do you happen to know anything like that?

Answer (score 4):

Grub2 can be configured for a [hidden menu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Hidden) which is displayed if you hold down the `Shift` key.